# Partial differentiability at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R,f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and $0$ otherwise. I have to study the continuity and partial differentiability of $f$ at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

$lim_{x\to0}f(x,x) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $lim_{x\to0}f(x,0)=0$. So it's discontinuos at $(0,0).$ The I computed:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{y^3-x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2} $ and

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{x^3-xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} $ and I don't know what should I do from here to check the differentiability at $(0,0)$. Can somebody give me some tips?

Comment: Those partial derivatives you computed assume $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$.  To compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$, you must use the limit definition of partial derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ can be obtained doing$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}h=\lim_{h\to0}0=0$$and, by a similar argument, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$ too.

But $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, since it is not even continuous there.